# Create record via client script in a relation model in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Could someone point me to documentation that shows how to create a record in a model with one to many relation via client side script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of creating a new record.

**1. Via a client-side script**

You can do this by calling a createItem function from a widget. This [link](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#CreateDataSource) might help with that.

**2. Via a server-side script**

You can do this by directly creating a new record, assigning it to the relation of a model and then saving that model. This [link](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations#server_script) might help with this method. By the way, it's easier to do this in a server-side script, as the guide itself says.

Since you just requested the link to official documentation, I've limited my answer to links only. Please feel free to ask if you need clarifications!